# Issue when changing table width from 100% to 75%

Tags: css, html-table

I'm using CSS code generated from: http://www.csstablegenerator.com/

The default has the table set at 100% and the table looks way too big--but when I reduced it to 75%, the right border still appears with some white space.

Here's the page I'm working on: http://www.patriciagambis.com/sizing-chart

I tried to paste the code here but was having too many issues with the validation from this text box--let me know if you need more info to figure out this problem.

--how can I fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Leave your table width to `100%`, and change the `.CSSTableGenerator` width to `75%`.

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
    width: 75%;
    /* ... */
}
.CSSTableGenerator table {
    width: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
```

**Bonus** : if you want your table to be centered, use this CSS :

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* ... */
}
.CSSTableGenerator table {
    width: 100%;
    /* ... */
}
```